# Is there a way to set jumbo frame with C++ in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

My C++ application uses Gige camera on many various Windows 10 PC.
So I wanna set jumbo frame of LAN card of PC programmatically. (when the process starts it is enabled and disabled when the end of process.)
any helps?

Comment: This is a registry setting. You can use PowerShell https://aidanfinn.com/?p=15166

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks for insight. I'll try using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @SimonMourier, I could write power shell command for enables jumbo frames and 1gbps duplex.

```
// enables.ps1

// Query all network adapter which has 'jumbo frame' property and set it as 9014 bytes.
$jumboFramesList = (Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -RegistryKeyword "*JumboPacket")
foreach($item in $jumboFramesList) {
  Set-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -DisplayName $item.DisplayName -RegistryValue "9014"
}

// Query all network adapter which has 'speed & duplex' property and set it as 1.0 gbps duplex.
$speedDuplexList = (Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -RegistryKeyword "*SpeedDuplex")
foreach($item in $speedDuplexList ) {
  Set-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -DisplayName $item.DisplayName -RegistryValue "6"
// Registry 6 means "1.0 Gbps duplex"
}
```

```
// reset.ps1
// Reset all network adapters' properties of 'jumbo frames' and 'speed & duplex'

$jumboFramesList = (Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -RegistryKeyword "*JumboPacket")
foreach($item in $jumboFramesList) {
  Reset-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name * -DisplayName $item.DisplayName
}

$speedDuplexList = (Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -RegistryKeyword "*SpeedDuplex")
foreach($item in $speedDuplexList) {
  Reset-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name * -DisplayName $item.DisplayName
}
```

and I could run above script files in my application when I need it.